# Argon2i password hashing and login for typo3 upgrade

Tags: authentication, typo3, password-hash, argon2-ffi

I was doing a typo3 upgrade from version 7 to 10. But got stuck with the fe users login section. Read in the documentation as salted passwords will automatically gets converted to argon2i hash values. This works for be users correctly. I have got a custom extension, where I will check whether the plaun text password is same as that of the password hash value in the database. My code is

```
if ($settings['feUserPid'] == $user['pid']) {
    $mode = 'FE';
    $success = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PasswordHashFactory::class)
                ->getDefaultHashInstance($mode)
                ->checkPassword($request->getArgument('password'), $user['password']);
}
```

Even if the password is correct, the value of $success is always FALSE. The passwords in the database is not argon2i hash value.
How can I fix this problem? Has anyone faced an issue like this?

Answer (score 2):

It's a while ago for me but I used

```
$hashInstance = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PasswordHashFactory::class)->getDefaultHashInstance('FE');
$hashedPassword = $hashInstance->getHashedPassword($x);
```

Your method should work. Did you verify the setting of [FE][passwordHashing][className] in the installtool?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Install tool setting is verified and it is set to "\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Crypto\PasswordHashing\Argon2iPasswordHash". What I need is to check is whether the current plain text password used to login is same as that of the password in database. Since it is an upgrade, the database contains old salted passwords. So for checkPassword method, the matching is not happening.

Comment: Do you use another process than the TYPO3 frontend login to login frontend users?

Comment: Users need to login first to get their password in Argon2i, else the database will contain the old password.

Comment: I am using a custom extension for frontend login. So in my custom extension i am comparing the passwords ie  new password and password already present in the database. Even if the password entering is correct, it is always returning false.

Comment: As you said, users need to first login for the passwords to get saved. But my custom extension is not allowing users to get logged in as it is always returning false for
GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PasswordHashFactory::class)->getDefaultHashInstance($mode)->checkPassword($request->getArgument('password'), $user['password']);

Comment: Why not just use the felogin extension and use the hooks typo3/sysext/felogin/Documentation/Hooks/Index.rst to implement your custom stuf

Comment: Since this is an upgrade and some extended third party functionalities are there, we are using this custom extension.

Comment: Okay then if compare fails with argon2i, compare after that with salting the user given password. If that works store the argon2i password.

Comment: Did  you mean to use password_hash function first to compare with the current password in database, and once if it passes, convert it to argon2i and save in database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235936/discussion-between-ques-and-jacco-van-der-post).